# Solving linear recurrence with binomials

Tags: recurrence-relations, binomial-coefficients, generating-functions

I need to solve linear recurrence
\begin{align}
a_n = \binom{9}{1}a_{n-1}-\binom{9}{2}a_{n-2}+\binom{9}{3}a_{n-3}-\dots+\binom{9}{9}a_{n-9}
\end{align} 
with initial conditions
\begin{align}
a_0=a_1=a_2=\dots=a_7=0, a_8=1 \space and \space n\ge9
\end{align}
I know method with generating functions, but i've stuck with binomials. Can anyone help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The corresponding characteristic equation is $$x^9 - \binom{9}{1}x^8+x^7\binom{9}{2}-...+x\binom{9}{8} - 1 = (x-1)^9 = 0.$$

Therefore, the general formula is given by $$a_n = c_0+c_1n+c_2n^2+...+c_8n^8$$. Now the rest is simply to solve a $9\times 9$ matrix equation using the initial condition.

Comment: Thank you, @dezdichado, I computed system of equations and it looks very ugly)

Comment: No problem. If you know some Linear Algebra , then using Cramer's would be much simpler than to solve 9 equations by hand because the vector $b = (0,0,...1)$ and the $9\times 9$ matrix $A$ is the Vandermonde's matrix whose determinant can be computed neatly.

Answer (score 0):

Use generating functions. Shift to write with no substraction in indices, multiply by $z^n$, sum over $n \ge 0$:

$\begin{align*}
a_{n + 9} z^n
  &= \sum_{0 \le k \le 8} 
       (-1)^k \binom{9}{k} a_{n + k} z^n \\
0
  &= \sum_{0 \le k \le 9}
       (-1)^k \binom{9}{k} a_{n + k} z^n
\end{align*}$

Note that:

$\begin{equation*}
  \sum_{n \ge 0} a_{n + r} z^n
    = \frac{A(z) - a_0 - a_1 z - \dotsb - z^{r - 1}}{z^r}
\end{equation*}$

By the particular initial values, we get:

$\begin{align*}
  0
    &= \sum_{0 \le k \le 9}
        (-1)^k \binom{9}{k} \frac{A(z)}{z^k}
        + \frac{z^8}{z^9} \\
  0
    &= A(z) \sum_{0 \le k \le 9}
              (-1)^k \binom{9}{k} z^{9 - k}
         + z^8 \\
  0
    &= - A(z) \sum_{0 \le k \le 9}
              (-1)^k \binom{9}{k} z^k
         + z^8 \\
  z^8
    &= A(z) (1 - z)^9 \\
 A(z)
    &= z^8 (1 - z)^{-9}
\end{align*}$

We want:

$\begin{align*}
  a_n
    &= [z^n] z^8 (1 - z)^{-9} \\
    &= [z^{n - 8}] (1 - z)^{-9} \\
    &= (-1)^n \binom{-9}{n - 8} \\
    &= \binom{n - 8 + 9 - 1}{9 - 1} \\
    &= \binom{n}{8}
\end{align*}$

(Nice way to confuse a rather simple recurrence).

Answer (score 0):

Note that we can also write, after shifting the recurrence:

$\begin{align*}
 0
   = \sum_{0 \le k \le 9} (-1)^k \binom{9}{k} a_{n + k}
\end{align*}$

But this is just the 9-th difference in $a_n$:

$\begin{equation*}
  \Delta^9 a_n
    = 0
\end{equation*}$

Now, if you take a polynomial of degree $m$, it's $m + 1$-th difference is zero. Thus $a_n$ is a polynomial of degree at most 8. Luckily, the initial conditions give the 8 zeros, so the polynomial is just:

$\begin{align*}
  a_n
    &= c n (n - 1) \dotsm (n - 7) \\
    &= c n^{\underline{8}}
\end{align*}$

Here we use the notation for falling factorial powers used e.g. by Knuth.

From $a_8 = 1$ we have that:

$\begin{equation*}
  a_8
    = c \cdot 8^{\underline{8}}
    = c \cdot 8!
\end{equation*}$

Thus:

$\begin{align*}
  a_n
    &= \frac{n^{\underline{8}}}{8!} \\
    &= \binom{n}{8}
\end{align*}$